# How to stop editing in TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So far I can edit my table view with this method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
[super setEditing:editing animated:animate];
if(self.isEditing)
{
    NSLog(@"editMode on");
    [leftButton setTitle:@"Edit"];
    [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Done leave editmode");
    [leftButton setTitle:@"Done"];
    [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];

}
}
```

I can get into edit mode and edit my table view, but when i click the button again it doesn't end the "Editing" mode. I've been trying to fix this for a while and am getting lost. All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: call [self setEditing:NO animated:YES] instead of super

Comment: Is this table view in a `UITableViewController` or in a `UIViewController`? How did you setup your left button? Make sure you use the standard `UIViewController` method `editButtonItem` to get a `Edit/Done` button. It will automatically call the `setEditing:animated:` method for you.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really make much sense. You're calling your superclass's implementation of setEditing:animated: multiple times on each execution, sometimes with different parameters. What you should be doing is letting the superclass execute the method with the same editing state as the subclass, and pull the logic for what state to set to the button press event. Something like this:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing
          animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    [super setEditing:editing
             animated:animate];

    if(self.isEditing) {
        NSLog(@"editMode on");
        [leftButton setTitle:@"Edit"];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Done leave editmode");
        [leftButton setTitle:@"Done"];
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self setEditing:!self.isEditing
            animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i programmatically added the button so i can't use IBAction

Comment: @doc92606 That was just an example. My point remains valid regardless of where you call setEditing:animated:.